# Recyclerview items invisible/ Missing when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

**Problem :**

My recyclerview item have one edittext.

*If user edit the edittext -> Keyboard will appear & some list items missing.* (means recyclerview shrink when keyboard open after keyboard close shrinked recyclerview not expanded)

**My xml design**

```
<ScrollView>
<ConstraintLayout>
  <other views>
  <recyclerview/>
</ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Manifest activity windowSoftInputMode**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Tried lot of google & SO. But no luck. Anyone give me solution. If anyone need more info let me know. I will give more details.

**UPDATE:**

My xml code - https://pastebin.com/diz4t9mp

**My issue - Video reference**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15J4hOnCM7Gu6uvklhzlSSD7XUCmmGmzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: post your layout here so everyone can have a look and able to help you asap

Comment: @Quicklearner full xml code here - https://pastebin.com/diz4t9mp

Comment: change scrollview height to wrap_content please and try

Comment: and use nestedscrollview instead of scrollview

Comment: if it still doesnt work set this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to adjust resize

Comment: @Quicklearner will try and let you know.

Comment: okay thanks let me know

Comment: @Quicklearner nestedscrollview working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change this**

```
<ScrollView>
<ConstraintLayout>
  <other views>
  <recyclerview/>
</ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

to

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<ConstraintLayout>
  <other views>
  <recyclerview/>
</ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

> `NestedScrollView` is used when there is a need for a scrolling view
>   inside another scrolling view. Normally this would be difficult to
>   accomplish since the system would be unable to decide which view to
>   scroll , it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android.